# Удаление из истории неверных команд

Tags: linux, bash, администрирование, логирование

Можно ли удалить неверные команды (возвратившие не 0) из `.bash_history` или не добавлять их туда вообще, чтобы файл содержал только полезную историю? При этом до выхода из терминала необходима возможность восстановить даже неверную предыдущую команду для удобства.

Например, такой флоу:

1. `lss` -> ошибка
2. восстанавливаю прошлую команду с помощью стрелки вверх
3. меняю `lss` на `ls` -> OK

В итоге в `.bash_history` должна быть только верная команда `ls` (хотя бы после закрытия сессии, а желательно после ввода верного варианта или всегда).

Comment: Проблема данной идеи в том, что даже верные команды могут возвращать "не ноль", к примеру `grep "abc" ./file` и в файле `file` не содержится *abc* завершится с кодом выхода не равным 0, хотя команда синтаксически верная

Comment: @ipatev_nn тогда если есть лучший критерий неверной команды, то использовать его, иначе достаточно решения для кода возврата

Comment: команда в лог скорее всего попадает до ее запуска, когда результат ее неизвестен... с другой стороны, одна и та же команда (даже просто cd folder) может вначале быть успешной, и тут же неуспешной. и что, удалять?

Comment: @KoVadim как это? в любом случае важна конечная успешность и конечная чистая история

Comment: тогда лучше написать свой (или доделать существующий) bash/zsh/dash/fish

Comment: @KoVadim лучше, чем что?

Comment: я даже не знаю, что  ответит на Ваше "чем что". Если Вам не нравится, как работает существующая программа - тогда можно взять и переписать так, как Вам нужно.

Comment: @KoVadim то есть из коробки в баше это невозможно сделать?

Comment: я такого не видел. и я выше написал, почему это скорее всего никто не делал.

Comment: ну, как-нибудь так: `$ export PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then history -d $(history 1 | awk "{ print $1 }"); fi'`. джихад, надеюсь, неверным командам объявлять не надо? // p.s. такой скрипт внутри PROMPT_COMMAND будет удалять команду, завершившуюся не нулём, сразу. если вы хотите добавить искусственный интеллект (угадать, что пользователь после получения ошибки выполняет ту же команду, но поправив ошибку, и потому удалить надо предыдущую команду, а не последнюю), то удачи вам!

Comment: А зачем вообще от туда что-то удалять? Поставьте лучше побольше число, что бы записывались все команды. Причем баш к этим командам отношения не имеет. За запоминание ввода отвечает `readline`. Базовая конфигурация задаётся через файлы `/etc/inputrc` и `~/.inputrc`. Пользуйтесь `bash-completion` и в частности поиском по истории через комбинацию `Ctrl+R`